# How to convert unioned generic list to generic list?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, lambda

I have two generic list that have been unioned.  Say listA and listB, both of type `List<SomeType>`.

```
listA.Union(listB);
```

The unioned set is of type `System.Linq.Enumerable.UnionIterator<string>`, which isn't the same as `List<SomeType>`.

I have tried casting:

```
listA.Union(listB).ToList<SomeType>();
```

and

```
(List<SomeType>)listA.Union(listB);
```

Both fail.  I tried to access ForEach(), thinking I could add the result to a new list.  .Foreach() isn't available.

I could use a traditional foreach and add each item to a `List<SomeType>` variable.  However, is there a lambda statement that can do the conversion in one line, assigning to a variable of type `List<SomeType>`?

Comment: Add .ToList() on the end listA.Union(listB).ToList();

Comment: please post your code.  The code you've posted would result in a `UnionIterator<SomeType>`, so ToList would solve your problem.  Since the actual object is a `UnionIterator<string>`, you must have something else going on -- a projection, perhaps, or some other confusion between SomeType and string.  (also, this will prevent you from pursuing the "traditional foreach" approach you mentioned).

Comment: Just so you know Union() will remove duplicate objects (If SomeType.Equals() is true) that are in both lists. If you want to keep duplicates you should use Concat()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly cast the List in `ToList` method. If both the list are of same type, you can simply do `ToList` in the end to get a List of the same type.

```
List<MyClass> listA = new List<MyClass>();
List<MyClass> listB = new List<MyClass>();
List<MyClass> temp = listA.Union(listB).ToList(); //Just do ToList at the end.
```

Explicitly specifying the type in ToList method should work as well. I am not sure why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

`Union` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` interface, not on `List<T>`, so it doesn't know or care that you are trying to connect lists and thus does not create one as a result unless you call `ToList` explicitly.

If you want to 'attach' one list to another, you might want to use `AddRange` method instead.